# VRay, FumeFX, and GI

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

So, I'm working on a model in 3DS Max that more or less has a physically-accurate glass lamp with a flame sticking out the top. The glass texture is a VRayMtl, and the problem is that in the FumeFX settings, to get sufficient light coming from it I've had to crank up the GI Modifier to 5. Although this has no impact on the appearance of the naked flame itself, when refracted through the glass texture it seems to take the flame's GI value into account and so appears wildly blown out and bright:

[image: render]

In 3DS Max 2012 this could be remedied simply by not using Refraction Interpolation in the glass texture settings, but recently I've updated to 3DS 2014, along with VRay 3.0.0.3 and FumeFX 3.5.4 (previously used versions were VRay 2.30.1 and FumeFX 3.0.1) and this no longer seems to yield the same result.